# How to show users in their area based on city, state, and country (and in that order)?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union, case

On one of my sites, I want to show our users people in their area.  Ideally, that would be users in their city.  However, some cities barely have any users, so I would also like to show users in their state.  However, some states barely have any users, so I would also like to show users in their country.

How would I go about doing this?

Thinking out loud, here's what I've come up with:

1) first show them the users in their city,

2) second the users in their state, and

3) third the rest of the users in their country

all in the same set of results, with each subset above ordered by the date of registration.  That way, if there are a lot of users in their city, they'll see them first.  If there aren't many, then they'll automatically see users in their state.  And if there aren't many in their state, they'll automatically see users in their country.  So regardless of whether they have many users in their city or state, they'll see plenty of results.

If that would be the correct way of doing it, then how would I do the query?  Would I do a `UNION` of 3 different queries from each of the above ordered by date of registration?  Would I use a `CASE` statement to order first by city, then state, then country, which each subset ordered by date of registration?  Some other way?

If the above is not the best way, then please describe a better algorithm and how I would query it.

Comment: what programming language are you going with? it's going to be a very complex SQL statement at best--you'll most likely want to do some filtering on the results after you make a basic query or two.

Comment: @jnunn: I'm using PHP.  How would you recommend approaching this issue to show users other users in their area?  Thanks.